# Not firing on server side onclick

Tags: javascript, c#, dom-events

I had set validation for a button called `valsave()` at the end of the validation I disabled the button.

Both validation and disabling function works properly, but server side onclick function for the same  button is not firing.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" TabIndex="16" SkinID="imgsave"
ToolTip="Save" OnClientClick="return valSave();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />

 function valSave()
 {


if(document.getElementById('hifMsgClick').value=='')
{
    vtxtPRequestDate=document.getElementById('txtPRequestDate');
    vdgvPurReq=document.getElementById('dgvPurReq');        

    if(vtxtPRequestDate.value.length==0)
    {
        showMsgbox('BLANK','Purchase Request Date','2','txtPRequestDate'); 
        return false;
    }        

   if(vdgvPurReq == null)  
   {
        showMsgbox('BLANK','Purchase Request Details','2','ddlItemRequestID');               
        return false;
   }

}    
else
{
    var vvalue=document.getElementById('hifMsgClick').value;   
    document.getElementById(vvalue).focus();
    document.getElementById('hifMsgClick').value="";
    return false;
}
  var vbtnSave=document.getElementById('btnSave');
  vbtnSave.disabled = true;  
  vbtnSave.value = 'Pls..wait';   
  __doPostBack('btnSave','OnClick'); }
```

How can I make the server side onclick fire?

Comment: so the page posts but the event handler doesn't execute or is that the the page doesn't post?  just want to make sure i understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just `return true;` ?

Comment: Can you show in your code sample where you tried this? It should work.

Comment: `var vbtnSave=document.getElementById('btnSave');
vbtnSave.disabled = true;  
vbtnSave.value = 'Pls..wait';   
__doPostBack('btnSave','OnClick'); return true;}`
       after the else part

Comment: You don't really need to do this - "__doPostBack('btnSave','OnClick');" Remove this and "return true" Should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fire onclick if you disable the button . so i suggest you to add one more button in hidden .like :

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" TabIndex="16" SkinID="imgsave" ToolTip="Save" OnClientClick="return valSave();" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnwait" runat="server" Text="Pls..wait" style="display:none" disabled="true" TabIndex="16" SkinID="imgsave" ToolTip="Save"  />
```

and then change your code like  this in your function

```
  document.getElementById('btnSave').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btnwait').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('btnSave').Click();
```

Thanks 
Gourav

Comment: it not raising any error and also not invoking the onclick method on serve side

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample for you to start of.   use .client id to get your control id . And make use of var in declaring variables.

```
 function valSave() {

    var mytext = document.getElementById("<%=hifMsgClick.ClientID%>").value;
    if (mytext == "") 
    {
      alert("No records found");
    }
    else 
    {
        //CLICK SAVE
        document.getElementById("<%=btnSave.ClientID%>").click();
    }

};
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

your function always return false because your if condition always return false

```
function valSave()
{


     if(document.getElementById('hifMsgClick').value=='')
     {
       return false;
     }
     else
     {
      return false;
     }

  // this part can not execute
 var vbtnSave=document.getElementById('btnSave');
 vbtnSave.disabled = true;
  vbtnSave.value = 'Pls..wait'; 
  __doPostBack('btnSave','OnClick'); }


}
```